# Python recursive tree example

Tags: python, recursion

I'm analying a bit of code in one of the Jenkins builds which uses recursion to get jenkins' downstream jobs' urls

```
def get_all_downstream_jobs_urls(ds_jobs: set = None):
    global JENKINS_JOBS

    if not ds_jobs: 
         ds_jobs = set(); ds_jobs.update(extract_ds_job_url(get_ds_jobs(BASE_JOB_URL)))

    temp = ds_jobs 

    for _ in ds_jobs.copy():
        result = extract_ds_job_url(get_ds_jobs(_)) # <--- jenkins rest api call
        if result: temp.update(result); JENKINS_JOBS.update(temp);
        else: return temp

    return get_all_downstream_jobs_urls(temp)
```

This works OK for a project which has downstream jobs although it's making too many calls to Jenkins rest api, but if a project doesn't have downstream jobs it is stuck in recursion. Could you help me figure out where the issue is?

Comment: I don't see any recursion here, unless `extract_ds_job_url()` or `get_ds_jobs()` make recursive calls. There is too much missing here to be able to help at all.

Comment: Also, `ds_jobs = set(); ds_jobs.update(...)` should just be `ds_jobs = set(...)`. The `global JENKINS_JOBS` line is redundant (nothing ever rebinds the name in the function). Don't use `_` for a variable name if you then actually use the value, `_` signals you intent to ignore the value. If it is a URL, name the variable `url`. `temp` is not a great name either, and you'd use `temp = ds_jobs.copy()` rather than create the copy for the loop.

Comment: udpated, the code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, this is not my code. keep this in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `extract_ds_job_url(get_ds_jobs(BASE_JOB_URL))` returns an empty set, you are forever calling `get_all_downstream_jobs_urls(temp)`. That's because the `for` loop is not going to do anything.

The test at the top should check for `None` instead:

```
if ds_jobs is None:
```

and a separate test for `ds_jobs` being empty should end the recursion:

```
if not ds_jobs:
    # no downstream jobs to process
    return set()
```

I can't vouch for the rest of the logic, but there are certainly many style errors in the code. I'd refactor it to *at least* get rid of some of those errors:

- `JENKINS_JOBS` is never rebound, so `global JENKINS_JOBS` is redundant and confusing and should be removed.
- It's not clear why the function is updating a global *and* is returning the result set. It should do one, or the other, not both.
- `_` is, [by convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python), a throw-away variable. It signals that the value is not going to be used. Yet here the code *does* use it. It should be renamed `job_url` instead.
- You really never should use `;` in production code. Put the code on separate lines.
- `ds_jobs = set()` then `ds_jobs.update(...)` is a way too verbose spelling of `ds_jobs = set(...)`.
- `temp` is not a good variable name, `updated` might be a better name. It should be made a copy when assigned, so `updated = set(ds_jobs)`, and the `.copy()` call can be removed from the `for` loop.
- the `return` when the first job URL doesn't have downstream URLs is probably not what you want either.
- If you really want a tree of downstream URLs, the recursive call should *not* try to pass in all job urls collected so far! It's just as likely to call the jenkins API again and again for a job URL that was already checked.

The following code removes the recursion by using a stack instead, and is guaranteed to call the Jenkins API for each job URL just *once*:

```
def get_all_downstream_jobs_urls():
    ds_jobs = set()
    stack = [extract_ds_job_url(get_ds_jobs(BASE_JOB_URL))]
    while stack:
        job_url = stack.pop()
        if job_url in ds_jobs:
            # already seen before, skip
            continue
        ds_jobs.add(job_url)
        # add downstream jobs to the stack for further processing
        stack.extend(extract_ds_job_url(get_ds_jobs(job_url)))
    return ds_jobs
```

Last but not least, I strongly suspect that using a third-party library like the [`jenkinsapi` package](http://jenkinsapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) would make this all even simpler; the Jenkins API probably lets you query this information in just one call but a library probably does such a call for you and give you readily-parsed Python objects for the information.

Comment: Great explanation and alternative code sample. thanks